# Data structure file input output

Tags: java, oop, object, file-io, io

I am trying to write a program which uses ArrayLists and file input output for a simple program.
The program should read a text file and store each field in an arraylist and then perform calculations. The file contains names of cities, population and country name. ie (London, 7500000,UK)
and when i run the program with a command line argument it should print statement saying how many of the cities have a population greater, equal to  the command line argument.

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Create a main method and then create `Scanner`/`BufferedReader` object to read a file and then split it by `,`. Keep storing them in your `ArrayList` and at last loop through arraylist and print them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice school exercise :-)

Assuming your input file in C:\temp\cities.txt contains :

```
London,83000000,UK
Paris,22000000,France
Madrid,32000000,Spain
```

The following class Test.java :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Test {

  private static ArrayList<City> loadDataFromFile() throws IOException {

    ArrayList<City> list = new ArrayList<City>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String sCurrentLine;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\temp\\cities.txt"));

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] splittedLine = sCurrentLine.split(",");
      City city = new City(splittedLine[0], Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[1]), splittedLine[2]);
      list.add(city);
    }

    br.close();
    return list;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<City> list = loadDataFromFile();
    int input = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    Iterator<City> it = list.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
      City currentCity = it.next();
      if (currentCity.getPopulation() > input) {
        System.out.println("Cities with population greater than " + input + " : " + currentCity.getName() + "," + currentCity.getCountry());
      } else if (currentCity.getPopulation() == input) {
        System.out.println("City with population equals to " + input + " : " + currentCity.getName() + "," + currentCity.getCountry());
      } else {
        System.out.println("Cities with population lower than " + input + " : " + currentCity.getName() + "," + currentCity.getCountry());
      }
    }

  }
}
```

and a simple POJO :

```
public class City {

  private String name;

  private int population;

  private String country;

  public City(String name, int population, String country) {
    this.name = name;
    this.population = population;
    this.country = country;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getPopulation() {
    return population;
  }

  public void setPopulation(int population) {
    this.population = population;
  }

  public String getCountry() {
    return country;
  }

  public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
  }

}
```

Will give you :

```
java Test 3200000

Cities with population greater than 32000000 : London,UK
Cities with population lower than 32000000 : Paris,France
City with population equals to 32000000 : Madrid,Spain
```

Answer (score 0):

Without giving a 'ready to run' answer, I think it should look something like this (pseudo code)

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    convert first argument to integer
    set up a reader for your file
    while (another line is found) {
      split the line by comma
      convert second item in array to an integer
      if integer >= integer passed in args
              print current line
    }
  }
```

Keep in mind that you have to do exception handling (IOExceptions, NumberFormatException etc). I deliberately didn't include saving to an arraylist, because that would mean you have to loop twice (once over the file and once over the list) which isn't necessary.